# API Testing / REST Assured Automation Testing Advice and or suggestions

Tags: json, testing, automated-tests, rest-assured, web-api-testing

Really looking for some practical advice and general guidance. 
Below is the current scenario.
I have an excel document each row would be considered a test with inputs.
There would be hundreds if not thousands of rows.
Lets for example say Row1 would look like

Col1----------|Col2---------------|Col3
TestingUser|TestingSurname|1980/01/01

This needs to me mapped to a JSON object then sent / POST to an API end point.
I then need to assert the data that is coming back to make sure it’s the correct values.
The tools I have looked at is:

ReadyAPI
rest-assured.io

Would you recommend any other tool or framework for this type of testing. 
If you have worked with something and you can provide an example that would be great.

Comment: `RestAssured` is great option to do that, I did similar tasks with combination of Java + JUnit + Rest Assured + Maven. You can read excel data with `jxl` or `apache-poi`, convert the data into JSON Objects with Rest Assured and return the JSON Objects in `@Parameters` annotation from JUnit. The parameter returned by `@Parameters` annotated method, will be a separate tests. You can also run them in parallel with `maven-surefire-plugin` with `<parallel>classes</parallel>`

Comment: Is there a way in java to have like a json template because only some items will be mapped and other required JSON objects will stay static. So what i am saying is have a JSON template then map excel data to specific JSON paths.

Comment: You can create `POJO` classes which will represent JSON object. Put static data in them and update the remaining ones with data from excel

Comment: @Flenters Try to do the following steps: 1. Import Rest Assured library via maven or import .jar file 2. Ready about POJO with Rest Assured and read data from excel sheet 3. Create classes representing JSON Objects, add static data and setters and getters for other data from excel 4. Use Object Mapper from Rest Assured to build JSON string 5. Try to create a simple request to your API with generated JSON 6. Read about `@DataProvider` or `@Parameters`, depends on the testing framework you use 7. Combine them together. That's basically what I would do and it will be complete solution

Comment: You can also ask individual questions so we can limit to a specific problem you might have. You can also contact me outside StackOverflow if you want to

Comment: I have started with the above trying to stay away from POJO at the moment so i have implemented a JSON template using https://velocity.apache.org/. So far so good thanks for the infoe @Fenio

Comment: You're welcome. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be able to provide recommendation as i haven't worked on RestAssured.However below are few advantages of ReadyAPI:

1. Learning curve is shallow,any Tester will be able to build test
   case without dependency on any programming language. ReadyAPI has
   inbuild feature to read data from different datasources(DB, XML,
   json,csv,excel etc.) and invoke REST endpoint by passing these
   fields to Header,query and Json Body of the end point.
   The response for each call can be dumped to a file using DataSink option for a 
   test step for each of the request calls made for the records from the file.
2. Tool is structured to easily build test Cases with multiple test
   Steps. It more like drag and drop to build your test cases.Hierarchy
   is Project -> Test Suite -> Test Case -> Test Step.
3. Easy integration with Jenkins CI/CD pipeline using testRunner with wide 
   variety of test reporting capabilities. Test reports are available as Allure, 
   jasper reports, junit Style reporting.
4. For more technical testers who need more control can use Groovy,javascript 
   language to build frameworks.
5. VirtServer and LoadUI are other tools by SmartBear that can be used to mock 
   services and run performance tests as desired.

I have an important comment to make here, if the file is huge(even 1000 lines) i have seen Ready API struggling as the tool does the heavylifting in the back. Hence would recommend to use groovy script utilizing Java API's for any file operations.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have created a class using velocity as a json template engine.

I have created a test and within that test i have a normal java loop.
This will loop through the entire xls, map values and and post to the API.

This is all working as expected. 
The problem is the runner displays
Default Suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 0,

However the loop does run x amount of times. 
How can i update it the when i execute the test its shows total tests run 10 or the same amount that is from the loop.

Hope this makes sense

```
@Test
public void generatePostData() throws IOException {
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("data\\sc1.xlsx"));
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        //Get Excel Data
        Cell testNumber = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1);
        System.out.println(testNumber.getNumericCellValue());
        //Velocity
        VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
        ve.init();
        //get the template
        Template t = ve.getTemplate("post.json");
        //create context and add data
        VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
        //map data
        context.put("tpltestNumber", testNumber);
        //render to stringWriter
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        t.merge(context, writer);

        baseURI = "someURL";
        Response response =
                given()
                        .contentType("application/json")
                        .body(String.valueOf(writer))
                        .when()
                        .post()
                        .then()
                        .assertThat()
                        .statusCode(200)
                        .extract()
                        .response();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to the question asked in the answers sesction by the reporter of the main question. (How to get the executed excel row count, for total executed test case count)

For that you have to pass the data using a method with DataProvider annotation.

[TestNG documentation](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html)

[DataProvider in TestNG](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/dataprovider-in-testng)

```
@DataProvider(name = "dp")
private Object[][] dataProvider() {
    Workbook wb;
    Sheet sheet = null;
    Object[][] excelRowArray = new Object[10][]; //this 10 the row count in the excel file

    try {
        wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("data\\sc1.xlsx"));
        sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {// Here 10 is the row count in the excel sheet
        //Get Excel Data row by row
        Cell testNumber = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1);
        System.out.println(testNumber.getNumericCellValue());

        // Create a object array with the values taken from a singe excel row
        Object[] excelRow = new Object[]{testNumber};

        // Add the created object array to the 'excelRowArray'
        excelRowArray[i - 1] = excelRow;

    }
    return excelRowArray;
}

@Test(dataProvider = "dp")
public void generatePostData(Object[] excelRow) {
    // Here single excelRow will be passed each time.
    // And this will run till all object[] in excelRowArray are finished.
    // Total tests executed will be the number of 'excelRow' object arrays in 
    // excelRowArray. (Or excel row count in the sheet)

    //Velocity
    VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
    ve.init();
    //get the template
    Template t = ve.getTemplate("post.json");
    //create context and add data
    VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
    //map data
    context.put("tpltestNumber", excelRow); // Here excelRow is used as the value
    //render to stringWriter
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    t.merge(context, writer);

    String baseURI = "someURL";
    Response response =
            given()
                    .contentType("application/json")
                    .body(String.valueOf(writer))
                    .when()
                    .post()
                    .then()
                    .assertThat()
                    .statusCode(200)
                    .extract()
                    .response();

}
```